# angular localStorage add to existing. key

Tags: javascript, angular

everyone,

I have a problem with localStorage and I don't know how to fix it. I have a form that is asking first for name and gender and on step 2 I have another form that is asking for weight and height. My data from step 1 is saved in localStorage but when I try to add the values from step 2 they just replace in localStorage with the step2 information instead of adding with the information from step 1. What can I do to fix it, if someone has time and can help I would appreciate a lot.

Regards,

TS. from step 1, this is how I store the step 1 form and its working.

```
submit() {
   
    localStorage.setItem('quizData', JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
  }
```

This is TS from step2 and its not working, I tried to push the values in the step 2 form but its just replacing the values in localStorage instead of adding them in the same key quizData.

```
submit() {
    let test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quizData') || '{}');

    let updated = test.push(this.form.value);

    localStorage.setItem('quizData', JSON.stringify(updated));

    console.log(test);
}
```

What can I do to be able do add both data from step 1 and step 2 instead of replacing the data. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `quizData`  from step 1 is an array or its an object..?

Comment: @Edison thanks for your response, its an object.

Comment: You are trying to push into an object, that's why

Comment: then pls chanege `let updated = test.push(this.form.value);` this line...here its assuming as array

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```ts
let test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quizData') || '{}');
let updated = { ...test, this.form.value };
```

Documentation: [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and I get (property) this: any
':' expected.ts(1005), so code doesn't compile because of this. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Could you please update the question to include the error?